# Is it possible to use a webapp to install and run third-party software on the user's local machine?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, architecture

My situation.

My company wants me to develop a webapp that will run 3rd party software on our client's machines. Basically, we developed some features for that software that we want our users to be able to use. However, the original software is very technical and we want to develop a simplified user interface that only provides the features that we developed, without the extra complicated bells and whistles.

The design passed down to me has this UI hosted on a webserver, but the software installed locally on the user's machine. However, this web-based UI is supposed to be able to execute commands to this locally installed software. (The person who designed this system seems to think this is possible to do with Javascript but I'm 99% sure it is not).

Putting aside the fact that this design doesn't make any sense (why wouldn't you just install the software on the server and run it there?), am I correct in believing that this would only be possible if we wrote a desktop program that would grant our webapp access to the user's local computer, and that we would have to get our user's to install it? Also, am I correct in thinking that this would be a security risk to our customers?

EDIT

My question is not about how to prompt the user to install the 3rd party software. My question is about how to issue commands to that software from a webapp.

Comment: there are purchase-able softwares such as "service now" that provide these solutions, and they come with really fancy bells and whistles, however, i'm not sure of it's licensing cost. So yes, what you asked is possible, although it is not done via javascript, it sends the request to another server, which takes it through several approvals, and then it triggers the windows software center, available in the enterprise windows, that installs it.

Answer (score 0):

What is the application written in? JavaScript and HTML (HTML5)? Or is it an actual installed type of application?

Can you write JavaScript that tells the user machine to install? Yes

Can you make sure it actually works? No, because it is not your computer.

Microsoft did one-click. The user still has to make some decisions, but if they said yes, it installed. There are similar paradigms in Java. If you want the "easiest", an offline website works, but realize it is a pain to actually debug.

But, your app is already written, so I assume you just want a magical install on the users machine so they can use it.

As far as one version of "how to". See [this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/native)

EDIT: Accessing desktop apps from a web app is possible, if the app has a command line way of running it (which you mention).  I am not sure how to do it in JavaScript, but I would look at running a command line application. In .NET, you have Process objects that can wrap the command line to get something running. This means putting the executable on the server and running it from a folder. For security, make sure that folder is inaccessible from people browsing, esp. if the app can create a huge security hole. If this presents a problem, you can also set it up behind an API internally, so it is behind a firewall and only allow HTTP access to the API from the external website.

You will have to figure the adapter to send the correct parameters to the command line to run and get your answer. Hopefully this uses command out, so you can just grab the information. If it writes files, you have another hurdle to leap.

NOTE: Technically there are ways of running apps with a full GUI this way, but it requires a lot of creativity and I would look at rewriting the functionality personally.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what language the 3rd party software is written in, but it has a command line interface that they want to use to interface with it through the webapp.

Comment: To clarify more.

There is a desktop app (written in Java I think, but I'm not sure) that is made by another company.

My company wants to issue commands to that other company's program, but the program is installed on local machines.

My question is not how to get the program onto the end user's device. My question is how to issue commands to that program from our web server.

Basically, they want users to be able to click a button on our web app (written in HTML and Javascript) that will cause the locally installed program to execute some action.